# Random number generation in mongodb within a range

Tags: json, mongodb

I have a collection in which I want to add a new field and in that field i want to randomly assign values between 1 and 44 in mongo db.

I have already tried math.random() which is not working.

{ $addFields:{ PoS_ID: { $switch:{ branches:[ { case: {$and : [{$gte: ["$user_id", 0]}, {$lte: ["$user_id", 10000]}]}, then:1 }, { case: {$and : [{$gte: ["$user_id", 10000]}, {$lte: ["$user_id", 15000]}]}, then:2 } ], default: -1 } } } }

This lets me assign pos_ids from 1 to 44 to different user ids based on conditions.But I want to simply assign each and every user id with a random number between 1 to 44.

Comment: Why not create the random number on the application side, craft a new document/update statement based on that, and insert it into the database?

Comment: can you explain this I did not understand.

Comment: If I want to keep values like assign them with 1 or 2 as pos_id instead of 1 only how can i do that?